# Get latest tweets through twitter search not working?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, tweets

I'm using the following code to get the latest tweets from a specific hashtag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
getLatestTweets();
function getLatestTweets(){
    var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23syria&result_type=recent&rpp=3&callback=?";

    $.getJSON(url, function(json){
        alert('reached');
        var html = '<ul>';
        $.each(json.results, function( key, result){
            html += '<li><a href="#">' + '> ' + result.text + ' ...' + '</a></li>'; 
        });
        html += '</ul>';
        $('#archive-twitter').append(html);
    });
}
});
```

this code was working fine two days ago but it stopped working today. now the getJSON method won't succeed even though that when i use the following link

> http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23syria&result_type=recent&rpp=3

in the browser i get the actual json data

i don't know what is the problem?

UPDATE: i added a test link to clarify the problem
http://latakiancoder.com/twitter-test.php

Comment: You should upgrade to API v1.1 which now require authentificated user. Seems like API v1 search has stop working using ajax request: https://dev.twitter.com/blog/planning-for-api-v1-retirement  But i cannot find any official announcement concerning this.

Comment: why the browser requests are working then!!, and can you provide any links or resources about authentication with jquery, i searched their documentation and didn't seem to find any thing about Javascript authentication. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried proxified server side the request and works:

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                getLatestTweets();
                function getLatestTweets(){
                    var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23syria&result_type=recent&rpp=3";

                    $.getJSON("proxy.php", { url: url }, function(json){
                        var html = '<ul>';
                        $.each(json.results, function( key, result){
                            html += '<li><a href="#">' + '> ' + result.text + ' ...' + '</a></li>'; 
                        });
                        html += '</ul>';
                        $('#archive-twitter').append(html);
                    });
                }
            });
```

proxy.php code:

```
<?php
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: thank you, i tried this and it worked in my localhost but when i uploaded the files to the server it didn't work. the first parameter of getJSON "proxy.php" is relative to what?

Comment: Its relative path of the proxy.php script. Here, is just at server root. So if you put it in a folder, just include it: myFolderWhereIsProxyScript/proxy.php. BTW, you should have allowed allow_url_fopen in php.ini or use CURL if enable on your server.

Comment: so i should put it on the root regardless of where my script files are stored? and another thing my website is on a shared hosting service. i have no access for the php.ini file, do i have any other options.

Comment: Just create/add a php.ini file inside proxy.php folder should be enough. This file should contains just one line: allow_url_fopen = On . And yes, in my example, the path was relative to index.php, if you call it form an other script, you have to use relative path from this script or use absolute path.

Comment: sorry, i didn't understand the first statement of your comment. did you mean to say i create a new folder and put both the proxy.php and php.ini inside it.

Comment: No, it was in case you have already put proxy.php inside a folder, not at root folder. If you have your proxy script in root folder (no sub folder), create a file at root folder, called it php.ini, edit it by adding just the line i told you before: allow_url_fopen = On. Save you new created php.ini file and try again. If your shared hosting service allow it, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is working fine at my end.

Make sure `include_entities` is set to `true` to get hashtag results.

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=ipl&result_type=recent&include_entities=true

After looking into the above url response Header:

```
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
```

Seems like twitter has retired API v1.

Comment: yes, i said that the url is working but the problem is that code inside getJSON method won't execute. Also i tried include_entities, nothing changed

Comment: thanks for replaying, but why the browser request results with the json data and my jquery request result in nothing!!

Comment: It checks for the same domain policy. By looking at the headers seems like cross domain XSS requests are now blocked.